# How to get the a href link from under the div class? using beautiful soup

Tags: python, html, web-scraping, beautifulsoup, css-selectors

I am trying to scrape the href attribute from links from a page, but I end up with `[]` as the output

[The HTML code is](https://i.stack.imgur.com/XsIcT.jpg)

My desired output is:
https://www.pigiame.co.ke/listings/nissan-latio-2016-36000-kms-5300124

Comment: From what URL is the HTML snippet you have in question?

Comment: when you click html you will see picture

Comment: There's no `<div class="listings-cards__list-item">` in the link you've provided.

Comment: no its not in the link click html code heading then you ll see picture

Comment: To get the results you want, I don't need the picture, I need the URL and observe from where the page is loading the data.

Comment: https://www.pigiame.co.ke/cars

Comment: I need all the links of cars posted and contact and or name from this link

Comment: [Please do not upload images of code/data/errors when asking a question.](//meta.stackoverflow.com/q/285551)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can try:

```py
import re
import requests
import urllib.parse
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup

url = "https://www.pigiame.co.ke/cars"

headers = {
    "User-Agent": "Mozilla/5.0 (X11; Ubuntu; Linux x86_64; rv:107.0) Gecko/20100101 Firefox/107.0",
}

soup = BeautifulSoup(requests.get(url, headers=headers).content, "html.parser")

links = [
    item.a["href"] for item in soup.select(".listings-cards__list-item:has(a)")
]

for link in links:
    soup = BeautifulSoup(requests.get(link).content, "html.parser")
    data = soup.select_one(".btn-whatsapp")["href"]
    data = urllib.parse.unquote(data)

    phone = re.search(r"phone=(.*?)&", data).group(1)
    print("{:<20} {}".format(phone, link))
```

Prints:

```
+254723099904        https://www.pigiame.co.ke/listings/nissan-note-5253578
+254722935411        https://www.pigiame.co.ke/listings/honda-freed-7-seater-2015-5291221
+254722763845        https://www.pigiame.co.ke/listings/2006-bmw-x3-2500cc-petrol-155000kms-5241375
+254722710833        https://www.pigiame.co.ke/listings/mazda-mpv-2006-5273382
+254713193417        https://www.pigiame.co.ke/listings/landrover-109-very-clean-accident-free-5282118
+254708467397        https://www.pigiame.co.ke/listings/landcrusser-prado-tx-fully-loaded-with-sunroof-2016-model-5304294
+254708467397        https://www.pigiame.co.ke/listings/landcrusser-prado-tx-fully-loaded-with-sunroof-5304293
+254708467397        https://www.pigiame.co.ke/listings/mistubishi-canter-2016-model-3tones-5304291
+254708467397        https://www.pigiame.co.ke/listings/hillux-revolution-2016-model-fully-loaded-5304288
+254708467397        https://www.pigiame.co.ke/listings/toyota-prado-2016-model-fully-loaded-with-sunroof-5304285
+254708467397        https://www.pigiame.co.ke/listings/toyota-prado-txl-diesel-fuel-2017-model-5304283
+254769333436        https://www.pigiame.co.ke/listings/toyota-fielder2015kdkbelow-50000km-5304279
+254708467397        https://www.pigiame.co.ke/listings/subaru-forester-sti-turbo-2016-model-5304280
+254769333436        https://www.pigiame.co.ke/listings/honda-fit2015kdkbelow-60000km-5304276
+254769333436        https://www.pigiame.co.ke/listings/honda-vezel2015kdklow-milleage-5304273
```

Comment: thanks alot but its only 15 rows how to get complete data of all pages with names too?

Comment: @Abduls Just put the code inside a loop and increase page `https://www.pigiame.co.ke/cars?page=2`, `https://www.pigiame.co.ke/cars?page=3`, ...

Comment: can you please tell me how
 to convert this data to dataframe of pandas